# How can I turn off the autocompletion when writing applescript in automator?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

It's very annoying for me that when I write the script, 3 dots appear and I can't continue to write my code because it jumps here and there.... does anyone know a solution for this? I would like to remove auto-completion from the code

I tried with the settings and keyboard commands, but unfortunately it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using *script editor* is a better way. It‘s a built-in app, also supports syntax highlight and code running.